# arduino analog read

Tags: ros, arduino, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

i'm trying to read an analog port from my arduino mega 2560 (Flex Sensor), but i don't know how to read and print the value of my sensor with a publisher in ros.

Can You HELP ME!!!

Thank you everybody

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47077/arduino-analog-read/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might try looking at RosSerial..

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

Or you can have a look here for some code utilizing Arduino and ROS.

[https://code.launchpad.net/~fuzzgun/buttonui-ros-pkg/trunk](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Efuzzgun/buttonui-ros-pkg/trunk)

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2